# Using JQuery UI Draggable objects, stack and z-index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a site that pops up draggable divs when certain links are clicked. This all works very well.

I'm also using the stack function to ensure that when divs are dragged, they are brought to the front. That also works well.

The problem I've got is that when a new link is clicked, if a previously dragged div is still open, the new div opens behind it - irrespective of z-index. If the previous div hasn't been dragged, the new window opens in front.

Is there a quick fix for this?

The JS I'm using for the dragging is:

```js
$(".window").draggable({
  handle: ".window-bar",
  containment: ".desktop",
  scroll: false,
  snap: ".desktop",
  snapMode: "inner",
  stack: ".window"
});
```

The code I use to add a new window is:

```js
$("a[data-window]").click(function(){
        const windowToOpen = $(this).data("window")
        $("input#start-menu").prop( "checked", false );
        $("#" + windowToOpen).show();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your code to make it clear

Comment: We need to see more of your code to help you. Specifically the part which moves the z-index when dragging, although a full MCVE would be preferable. My first thought would be to put a class on the active element which sets the z-index to be above the others. Then you can select that class and remove it when a new element is added.

Comment: Sorry, have added the basic elements of the code that deal with new windows and dragging.

Answer (score 2):

Try to stack your `divs` which has `window` class instead of worrying about `z-index` and for showing the div at top after click but not dragged you need to use the following code.

So for stacking you need to add `stack: "div"` and for showing the div element on the top by simply click, you need to use `distance: 0`.

By default the value is `distance: 10` which means until you don't drag it to 10 pixels, it won't show up on the top. By setting the value to `distance: 0`, makes it to be visible on top of everyone as soon as you clicks.

**In your case:**

```
$(".window").draggable({
  handle: ".window-bar",
  containment: ".desktop",
  scroll: false,
  snap: ".desktop",
  snapMode: "inner",
  stack: ".window",
  distance: 0
});
```

---

**Working Example Below:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#container .window").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: 'parent',
    stack: ".window",
    distance: 0
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}

.window {
  min-width: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  min-height: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: white;
  position: fixed !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.window h4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  background: GREEN;
  color: White;
}

#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #666666;
}

#container>div:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#container>div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}

#container>div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 60px;
  top: 60px;
}

#container>div:nth-child(4) {
  left: 90px;
  top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="window">
    <h4>ONE</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <h4>TWO</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <h4>THREE</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content window">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">FOUR</h4>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank, the Distance option is helpful. However, I still face the issue that if I generate a new window, that new window always appears under previously moved windows.

Comment: For that, you just need to add a new window with a maximum index value i.e., `z-index: 999999`. By adding this value to the newly generated item, your new window will pop up at front and whenever a user tries to drag or click on it, it's `z-index` is adjusted by the library and you don't have to worry about maintaining and calculating the `z-indexes`.

Comment: That's the issue. It doesn't matter if your new window has a z-index of 999999, it will always appear under the last moved div.

I'm trying to see whether I can fix using the stop: event, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please share your HTML code in your question as well in order to let me see what's the problem you are facing.